# `this` in a variable assigned by an element with inline javascript is valid for all elements or the active element which has assigned the value

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I was thinking that, if we add `this` attribute to a element's onlick event like `onclick="a=this"`. In this step are selecting the "p" element or the variable `a` can be used as an alternative to `this`.

**See this code-**

```
 <p onclick="a=this">Click me to assign value<b> this</b> to variable<b> a</b></p>

 <p>This is Another paragraph will this be affected</p>

 <button onclick="a.style.visibility='hidden'">
 When this button will be clicked, what will happen?, "button" will become invisible or "p"
 </button>
```

Suppose if we click on the first paragraph and then click on the button which element/elements will become invisible. Will the button get affected from it or the first paragraph or may be the other paragraph as well?

I used Google to find more on this topic but didn't got anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it will hide the first paragraph as you're assign `this` as a global variable `a`: http://jsfiddle.net/cJDNf/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but please tell me what is this `jsfiddle.net`. And thanks once again.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a tool that lets you try out html, css and javascript ideas on the fly. It's a great tool for when you want to experiment with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The first paragraph will become invisible only. But you might need to initialize `a` as global variable, or maybe not.

Comment: I think that a variable declared by in-line JavaScript is already a global variable. I think you should read my question once again to give a better answer. Tell men how the other elements will be affected

Comment: as I said only first paragraph will be invisble nothing else. You are right when you said 'a' is a global variable. I always explicitly initialized variables globally to be safe, but it is not required here.